# Inheritance from non-protocol type 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horizontal collection view in my project which has 2 elements - a button and a label. Button and label are stuck to each other and then I want to show other button and label within the cell with space between 2 elements i.e. Button 1 and label 1, then some space and then display button 2 and label 2. Want to have some space between label 1 and button 2.

I came across some 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout' related methods and did try adding the code for it to test, but the functions are not getting called. Below are the functions:

```
extension MyController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)
    }
}
```

However adding 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout' is giving me `"Inheritance from non-protocol type 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout'"` error.

How can I get 'minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt' and other methods executed? Or how can I add space between label 1 and button 2, and then space between label 2 and button 3?

Comment: it's a ```UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout``` not UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is private function. can we use that?

Answer (score 4):

It is `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: saves the day. Thanks